# page redirection on other website with query string

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, query-string

i have a website "A" in which i am login and redirecting to page "A1" there one text box is asking entry code after filling that code there is a btn GO when i press that btn its redirecting to page "A2" based on that entry code all text filed gets fill. in that page "A2" I have a btn "SAVE & GO to website B"

now wht i want to Based on that entry code i want to redirect to "website B" in new browser on save and go to website B btn.

i am using the code

```
protected void btnSaveCase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Session.Abandon();
           Response.Redirect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["website B"] + "/Content/CaseProps.aspx?CaseId=" + geturl(CaseId.ToString()));
          //Response.Redirect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RCMS"], true);

        }
```

but its not working...

can i use some other code??

anyone please help me...

Comment: do you want to open a new window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
Response.Redirect("URL", false);

Response.Redirect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["website B"] + "/Content/CaseProps.aspx?CaseId=" + geturl(CaseId.ToString()), false);
```

By setting it to `false`, it will terminate your current request.

Comment: ya its working but its not opening in new window i am using OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';"

Comment: you can try something like, if you want it open another window. Response.Write("<script>window.open('URL');</script>");

Comment: i want to open website B in new window will your code work? Response.Redirect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["website B"] + "/Content/CaseProps.aspx?CaseId=" +CaseId.ToString());

Comment: i am unable to implement same code with this will you please let me know

Comment: Response.Write("<script>window.open(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RCMS"],true);</script>"); this is the code i am writting

Comment: above code is working but when it is redirecting to Website B.. Website A's all CSS is getting affected.

Answer (score 0):

If the error is that the redirect does not take you to website B then its most probably because you are storing the website b in `AppSettings` incorrectly. Please store the website B with `http://` prefix like this.

```
<add key="website B" value="http://www.websiteb.com"/>
```

Ok. So you want to open a new window rather than redirecting. Try this then.

```
protected void btnSaveCase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Session.Abandon();
        string features = "menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";
        string name = "mywindow";
        string url = String.Format("{0}/Content/CaseProps.aspx?CaseId={1}",
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["website B"],
            geturl(CaseId.ToString()));
        string script = String.Format(@"window.open('{0}','{1}','{2}');",
            url,
            name,
            features);
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "key", script, true);
    }
    catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException)
    {
        throw;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

On an unrelated side note, its a good practice to use `WebsiteB` instead of `website B` in `AppSettings`

Comment: i am want to open a new browser window on my btn click but i am unable to do it... my code is protected void btnSaveCase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Session.Abandon();                     Response.Redirect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RCMS"], true);                      
        } any open please help me to open redirect my url in new window